# Can't load Maya plugin

Tags: plugins, maya

I want to add the MoCapX Maya plugin with Maya 2018. I downloaded the plugin (which included icons, plug-ins, and scripts folders). In C:{username}\Documents\maya\2018, I edited the Maya.env file to

`MAYA_MODULE_PATH=D:\Downloads\MocapX`

which is the file path to the plugin. When I open Maya's Plug-in Manager, the plug-in appears but when I check the loaded checkbox I get.

```
// Error: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/pluginWin.mel line 290: Unable to dynamically load : D:/Downloads/MoCapX/plug-ins/mocapx_plugin.mll
The specified procedure could not be found.
 //
// Error: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/pluginWin.mel line 290: The specified procedure could not be found.
 (mocapx_plugin) //
```

Any ideas? I also cleared the prefs by renaming the prefs folder to oldPrefs but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, whenever this error pops up, maya has trouble finding certain .dll files or other important files for the plugin.

Have you tried moving the Plugin to your current versions plugin folder ?
This could eliminate some path problems while loading.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like the plugin might have a dependency to a script file. This could be an AETemplate file, if the plugin creates dependency nodes for instance.

The variable `MAYA_MODULE_PATH` is not looking for scripts and plugins but is looking for a `module file`.

A module file has it's own variables inside to tell maya where to find scripts and plugins.

Check the Maya 2018 help [Distributing Multi-File Modules](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_CB76E356_753B_4837_8C5B_3296C14872CA_htm) for information about how to create a module file that maya will recognise and allow the plugin to load with its respective scripts and resources.

To confirm that the plugin works in the first place, you could copy the scripts to the `scripts` folder in Documents/maya/2018/scripts
and the plugin to the `plug-ins` folder Documents/maya/2018/plug-ins.
If you still get the same error, then it's not a problem with distribution but then there is something broken in the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in Win 10/Maya 2018.5:

- download the latest version of the plugin (mocapx_2.2.1_Maya2018_win) from:
  [Mocapx Plugin download][1]
  [1]: https://www.mocapx.com/download/
- extract the contents of the folder to:

C:\Program Files\Mocapx (DO NOT create SUBFOLDERS!!)

- Go to :
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAMEHERE\Documents\maya\2018

and add this line with Notepad:

MAYA_MODULE_PATH=C:\Program Files\Mocapx

- Make sure that shelf_MocapX.mel is located at:
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAMEHERE\Documents\maya\2018\prefs\shelves

Hope this helps!

LAO